# SO "flagged answer" deleted instead of edited

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-answer

I believe I have mistakenly asked for an answer on SO to be deleted, when I actually wanted it edited...

I flagged the one and only answer on the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009796/net-form-not-loading-inside-thickbox-window) on SO, because the answerer (who was the OP in the first place) had mis-formatted their answer.  They had put `<form runat="server">` as part of their text, but not used the ` character, therefore the tag became "invisible".

I would have edited it myself, but it would have only need 2 characters changing (less than the required 6), and would then have required peer-reviewing... so instead I placed a comment on the answer stating this.  Nothing happened, so I decided to contact a mod via the flag, so say it needed editing.

However, the answer has now completely vanished, and I'm worried that I have given the wrong impression to the moderator!  (Despite the flag being marked as "helpful")

Is there any way to retract it, or contact the mod who did it, as I can't see anything obvious?

**EDIT**

<strike>Looking at the list of questions on SO, the question is showing as updated by "Daniel Fischer", despite there being no obvious activity by him.  Is there anyway of contacting Daniel directly?  I know there is no "private message" facility within Stack Exchange.</strike>

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Thanks to @JamesAllardice, he has been able to highlight that Daniel did not delete the answer, but actually edited it as it needed to be. I will leave the situation alone for the time being, and hope the dust settles accordingly.

Comment: I can't say why the question was deleted, but I would not use a moderator flag for edit suggestions. Leave a comment as you have. And perhaps it will be picked up by those with edit privileges. Though some moderators are prolific editors as well, I assume they have more than enough to deal with already.

Comment: Note that a moderator deleted the question, not Daniel.

Comment: @Bart, I did wonder if flagging was a good idea in the first place... regretting it now. I will put a comment on the question to try and explain the situation, and grovel at the same time

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, how are you able to tell, or is it that only moderator's are able to delete, and Daniel simply isn't a moderator?

Comment: Perhaps just wait for a little bit until the situation is clarified. No need to wake anybody up when you're not sure why it was deleted. The decision might not have been directly caused by your flag.

Comment: @freefaller - Users with 10k rep can see the deleted answer. Daniel has edited it to include the code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @James, I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: SO is cooperatively edited.  No need to flag mods to edit stuff.  We have enough crap to deal with.  Just edit it yourself.

Comment: My apologies @Won't, please put it down to my stupidity and naivety. I appreciate the level of crap you get, which is why I have massive respect for your guys, and could never do it myself (I was a mod on a tiny, tiny site in comparison to SO, and I couldn't even cope with that!)  Although, it didn't help when the minimum number of characters to edit is 6.

Comment: @freefaller - Looks like it's been undeleted now :)

Comment: Thanks again @James - looks like I will be able to get some sleep tonight after all ;-) As there is no definitive answer to this one, I guess we just have to leave it as unanswered